# Can I cook my apple butter on high when it suggests low?

Tags: butter, apples

I am cooking apple butter in a slow cooker and the recipe calls for 1 hr on high and then 9 hours on low. My slow cooker only cooks on high.. Can I cook it on high for a shorter amount of time without compromising the flavor, etc?  Thanks

Comment: As it thickens, Apple sauce becomes quite prone to burning on the bottom of the pan. I make Apple butter on a gas stove, and after the initial boiloff, it really demands that the heat be turned *way* down. Barely a simmer, with plenty of stirring. Perhaps the crock pot method is easier, but I'd be very wary of excess heat.

Answer (score 2):

While different cookers have different opinions about how hot "high" and "low" actually are, I still wouldn't gloss over such a large discrepancy, unless I knew enough to make the call.

However, you can easily lower the temp of your crockpot on it's high setting. Try putting a terrycloth rag between the metal case and ceramic pot. This will reduce the heat transfer from the coils to the food, resulting in a stable but lower temp. Use a thermometer to check before/after temps and adjust the amount of "insulation" to get the temp you want. Low on my cheap consumer crockpots is around 120-140F.